Empty body on alert trading view webhook
I'm currently testing some indicator/strategy and would like to automate things.
I configure somes webhook with alerts with JSON formated strings like :
alert("{'heyyy':'oohhhh!'}", freq = alert.freq_all)  

but when the alert is triggered, webhook sended and i reveive the call on my server (node.js), the body is empty : {}
i setup the alert on "every alert() call"
i also try with alertcondition but the result is the same : empty body.
Thanks

Webhooks from the script are sent in text/plain format. Did you try get raw content?
If this doesn't help, please, share the minimum code of your server processing the request and the libraries used.

HI, . i also tried with strategy.entry (since my script was originaly a strategy) but even if i put strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long, limit=entry, comment=commentJSON ) and configure the message in the alert like {"data":"{{strategy.order.comment}}"} , the webhook arrived always empty.
i'll put some details about my back later but its nothing complicatedd.. just a node.js/express backend and i just console.log(req.body)  so nothing complicated. I just think i miss something in the webhook + alert workflow

I figure how to do that, there were a few issues
1 - We must use simple quote as wrapper and double quotes for properties in stringify JSON
str = "{'hey':'oh!'}" // bad
str = '{"hey":"oh:"}' // good

2 - server side (node JS) my body parser is now setup to receive plan text too
 app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "*/*" }));

Note, if your JSON string is setup with the wrong quotes , the JSON.parse() won't work
